# A question on ramification groups in Milne

Tags: solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT301.pdf
Look at page 123 of these notes.
[image]

Consider this
$$\sigma \in G_0 \Leftrightarrow |\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha| < \pi ^0, \forall \alpha \in B \Leftrightarrow v_{\pi}(\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha) \geq 1, \forall \alpha \in B \Leftrightarrow \sigma(\alpha) \cong \alpha \mod \mathfrak{p}, \forall \alpha \in B,$$
so $G_0$ is the usual inertia group that I already knew.

Is it wise to do the same for $G_{-1}$? Consider this
$$\sigma \in G_{-1} \Leftrightarrow |\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha| < \pi ^{-1}, \forall \alpha \in B \Leftrightarrow v_{\pi}(\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha) \geq 0, \forall \alpha \in B \Leftrightarrow \sigma(\mathfrak{p})= \mathfrak{p}, \forall \alpha \in B,$$
I can not do the last implication. If I can do it, then $G_{-1}$ is the usual decomposition group that I already knew.

$$v_{\pi}(\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha) \geq 0, \forall \alpha \in B \Leftrightarrow \sigma(\mathfrak{p})= \mathfrak{p}, \forall \alpha \in B$$
Why we have this implication?

I can just show this
$$v_{\pi}(\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha) \geq 0, \forall \alpha \in B \Rightarrow \sigma(\mathfrak{p}) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}, \forall \alpha \in B.$$
If the valuation is preserved under the action of $\sigma$, $v(\sigma(\pi))=v(\pi)$, then I can show this
$$v_{\pi}(\sigma(\alpha)-\alpha) \geq 0, \forall \alpha \in B \Rightarrow \sigma(\mathfrak{p}) = \mathfrak{p}, \forall \alpha \in B.$$

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself after an hour. For the direct implication observe that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p})$ is another prime, but in local fields there is only one unique prime. The reverse implication is quite easy, both of $\alpha$ and $\sigma(\alpha)$ are integral, so their valuation is nonnegative. In local fields the decomposition group is the whole Galois group.